# How to construct Legendre polynomials for $x_1,...,x_k$?

Tags: orthonormal, legendre-polynomials, multivariate-polynomial

I'm trying to run a nonparametric regression to estimate the unknown conditional mean $E(Y|X_1=x^*_1,X_2=x^*_2)$ using data set $\{Y_i,X_{1i},X_{2i}\}_{i=1}^n$. This could be done by nonparametric series regression: first construct $K$-th order polynomial regressors $r_1(x_1,x_2),...,r_K(x_1,x_2)$ and then regress $Y_i$ on $r_1(X_{1i},X_{2i}),...,r_K(X_{1i},X_{2i})$ and use the predicted value at $(x_1^*,x_2^*)$ as our estimate.  I plan to use the $K-$th order Legendre polynomials in $x_1,x_2$,and I'm wondering how shoud I construct them? From linear algebra notes I found that if I only have one variable $x$ then the up-to-3rd order Legendre polynomials are: 1, $x$, $\frac{3x^2-1}{2}$, $\frac{5x^3-3x}{2}$. I'm wondering what are the corresponding Legendre polynomials when I have $x_1,x_2$? A formula, recursive formula, reference or software package/function that generates this are all ok. Thanks

Comment: Perhaps you can use this [two-dimensionalLegendre polynomials](https://www.sciencepubco.com/index.php/ijamr/article/download/8198/2904)

Comment: Your title seems misleading @ExcitedSnail. Legendre polynomials are nothing but the orthogonalization of our familiar polynomial basis $\{1,x,x^2,\cdots\}$

Comment: @NN2 Thank you very much! This is very helpful and has the exact formula I need!

Comment: @N00BMaster You are right. I guess I just don't know how to get expressions for othogonalized version of $\{1,x_1,x_2,x_1^2,x_2^2,x_1x_2,...\}$ given some inner product.